# r Sunburst element when knit to html shows code instead of interactive plot

Tags: html, r, knitr

I have a sunburst plot code that works as intended inside the Rsutdio. But when I knit it to an html document it only shows the code instead of the actual plots. No error shown when knitting. The code contains a "for loop" to create 4 sunburst plots with different data.

```
taxonomy <- read.delim("~/Test_Folder/nfcore_ampliseq/qiime2/abundance_tables/abs-abund-table-4.csv")
samples16s<- colnames(taxonomy)[-c(1,2,3,4)]
samples16s
summary(taxonomy)
#Remember to check whether all we find in the data is indeed Bacteria 

#Add a color function for the sunburst
colore <- colorRampPalette(c("#40dc3d", "#4d79d7"))


for (i in samples16s) {
  df <- cbind(taxonomy[c(2,3,4)],taxonomy[i]) #Separate the different samples into their own dataframe 
  names(df)[4] <- "size" #rename the column so that sunburst recognizes it properly.
  tree <- d3_nest(df, value_cols = "size") #create the tree
  sb <- sund2b(tree, color=colore(15), width="100%", showLabels = TRUE, rootLabel = "Bacteria") #create the sunburst visualization
  print(div(
    style="display: flex; align-items:center;",
    sb
  ) )
}
```

As i said, the code runs fine inside Rstudio and produces the expected interactive objects. But when knitted to an html file output it shows the following for each of the objects:

```
## <div style="display: flex; align-items:center;">
##   <div id="htmlwidget-dc9373b627b6f237b124" style="width:100%;height:500px;" class="sund2b html-widget"></div>
##   <script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-dc9373b627b6f237b124">{"x":{"data":{"root":{"children":[{"name":"Margulisbacteria","children":[{"name":"WOR-1","children":[{"name":"O2-12-FULL-45-9","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Bacteria","children":[{"name":"Bacteria","children":[{"name":"Bacteria","size":6,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Omnitrophota","children":[{"name":"Koll11","children":[{"name":"GIF10","size":36,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"2-02-FULL-51-18","size":0,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"UBA6215","size":0,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"2-01-FULL-45-10","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"},{"name":"Omnitrophia","children":[{"name":"Omnitrophales","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Methylomirabilota","children":[{"name":"Methylomirabilia","children":[{"name":"Rokubacteriales","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Gemmatimonadota","children":[{"name":"Gemmatimonadetes","children":[{"name":"Gemmatimonadales","size":6,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Acidobacteriota","children":[{"name":"Mor1","children":[{"name":"Gp22-AA2","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Patescibacteria","children":[{"name":"ABY1","children":[{"name":"BM507","size":0,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"SG8-24","size":0,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"ABY2","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"},{"name":"Patescibacteria","children":[{"name":"Patescibacteria","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"},{"name":"Paceibacteria","children":[{"name":"UBA9983","size":0,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"UBA10092","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"},{"name":"Gracilibacteria","children":[{"name":"Peribacterales","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Proteobacteria","children":[{"name":"Gammaproteobacteria","children":[{"name":"Burkholderiales","size":323,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"Acidiferrobacterales","size":8,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"Pseudomonadales","size":294,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"Gammaproteobacteria","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Nitrospirota","children":[{"name":"Thermodesulfovibrionia","children":[{"name":"UBA6902","size":0,"colname":"X.2"},{"name":"Thermodesulfovibrionales","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"},{"name":"Nitrospiria","children":[{"name":"Nitrospirales","size":24,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Desulfobacterota","children":[{"name":"GWC2-55-46","children":[{"name":"GWC2-55-46","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Firmicutes","children":[{"name":"Bacilli","children":[{"name":"Bacilli","size":22,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Desulfobacterota_E","children":[{"name":"MBNT15","children":[{"name":"MBNT15","size":0,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"},{"name":"Bacteroidota","children":[{"name":"Bacteroidia","children":[{"name":"Chitinophagales","size":5,"colname":"X.2"}],"colname":"X.1"}],"colname":"X"}],"name":"root"},"tooltip":null,"breadcrumbs":null},"options":{"colors":["#40DC3D","#40D448","#41CD53","#42C65E","#43BF69","#44B873","#45B17F","#46AA8A","#47A394","#489CA0","#4995AB","#4A8EB6","#4B87C1","#4C80CB","#4D79D7"],"valueField":"size","rootLabel":"Bacteria","showLabels":true}},"evals":[],"jsHooks":[]}</script>
## </div>
```

I've tried doing it without the loop (individual calls for each object) and it works fine once knitted. What is wrong with my loop for it not to knit the object into the html?

**EDIT**
I tried using lapply instead of a loop but it did not work either when knitting:

```
#Sunburst as a function
sunburst <- function(sample, tax){
  df <- cbind(tax[c(2,3,4)],tax[sample]) #Separate the different samples into their own dataframe 
  names(df)[4] <- "size" #rename the column so that sunburst recognizes it properly.
  tree <- d3_nest(df, value_cols = "size") #create the tree
  sb <- sund2b(tree, color=colore(15), width="100%", showLabels = TRUE, rootLabel = "Bacteria") #create the sunburst visualization
  print(div(style="display: flex; align-items:center;",sb))
}

lapply(samples16s, sunburst, taxonomy)
```

**EDIT 2**
Sample data
|#OTU ID||||sampleID_1|sampleID_1a|sampleID_2|sampleID_2a|
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|Bacteria|Margulisbacteria|WOR-1|O2-12-FULL-45-9|0|20|0|26|
|Bacteria|Bacteria|Bacteria|Bacteria|6|93|0|83|
Bacteria|Omnitrophota|Koll11|GIF10|36|0|79|0
Bacteria|Methylomirabilota|Methylomirabilia|Rokubacteriales|0|23|0|18
Bacteria|Gemmatimonadota|Gemmatimonadetes|Gemmatimonadales|6|0|4|0
Bacteria|Acidobacteriota|Mor1|Gp22-AA2|0|4|0|17
Bacteria|Patescibacteria|ABY1|BM507|0|13|0|13
Bacteria|Proteobacteria|Gammaproteobacteria|Burkholderiales|323|17|527|24